# How to add album art to mp3 file using python 3?

Tags: python, audio, python-3.4, eyed3

I was wondering what module to use for setting an image as the album art for a particular mp3 file. Mutagen seemed to be a popular choice, but it doesn't seem to work on python 3 and I can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 27):

Here's a modified version of the code I use. You will want to change the `example.mp3` and `cover.jpg` (and perhaps the mime type too):

```py
import eyed3
from eyed3.id3.frames import ImageFrame

audiofile = eyed3.load('example.mp3')
if (audiofile.tag == None):
    audiofile.initTag()

audiofile.tag.images.set(ImageFrame.FRONT_COVER, open('cover.jpg','rb').read(), 'image/jpeg')

audiofile.tag.save()
```

`tag.images.set()` takes three arguments:

- **Picture Type**: This is the type of image it is. `3` is the code for the front cover art. You can [find them all here](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Attached_picture).
- **Image Data**: This is the binary data of your image. In the example, I load this in using `open().read()`.
- **Mime Type**: This is the type of file the binary data is. If it's a `jpg` file, you'll want `image/jpeg`, and if it's a `png` file, you'll want `image/png`.

Comment: You forgot one line:

audiofile.tag.save()

Comment: @Jordan You're absolutely right. I've edited the code to add that line I'd left off the end. I'd left it off because I do a bunch more editing to tags before I save the tag!

Comment: What about if i want to display the image from `audiofile,tag,images[0]`?

Answer (score 9):

an addition to answers above, here is what I struggled on for two days:

- you have to set the ID3 version to "V2.3", otherwise the photo won't show up for the file icon.
- also you have to set a different album name for each MP3 file because otherwise the music player shows the same cover image for all music files even if they don't have a cover image.
- you'd better set a title too because file name won't be displayed in music players.
- using the `audio.initTag()` can also wipe all meta information if you would want that.

```py
audio.initTag()
audio.tag.title = u'Your Title'
audio.tag.album = u'Your Album Name'
audio.tag.images.set(3, open("cover.jpg", 'rb').read(), 'image/jpeg')
audio.tag.save(version=eyed3.id3.ID3_V2_3)
```

Comment: This works a dream. Setting the version number does indeed make windows explorer pick up artwork image.

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing [**`mutagen`**](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/id3.html) already works fine with python3.

Copy-paste from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47346660/191246 with the tiny fix of adding the binary file mode for the image which is required with python3.

```py
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, APIC, error

audio = MP3(path_mp3, ID3=ID3)
audio.tags.add(
    APIC(
        encoding=3,  # 3 is for utf-8
        mime="image/png",  # can be image/jpeg or image/png
        type=3,  # 3 is for the cover image
        desc='Cover',
        data=open("cover.png", mode='rb').read()
    )
)
```

> NOTE: you might want to wrap in a `try-except` in order to catch `ID3NoHeaderError` which will be raised on MP3 files without an ID3 tag. In those cases you can create the tag with e.g. `tags = ID3()...`  followed by `tags.save('myaudio.mp3')`