# Mutagen: How can I "correctly" embed album art into mp3 file so that I can see the pitcure display as file icon

Tags: python, mp3, flac, mutagen, albumart

I am trying to convert flac files to mp3 format, using [`pydub`](https://pypi.org/project/pydub/) for conversion and [`mutagen`](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for tags and album art copy.

Convert a flac file to a 320Kbps mp3:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

path_flac  = 'mc_test/from/01 Lapislazuli.flac'
path_mp3   = 'mc_test/to/01 Lapislazuli.mp3'
flac_audio = AudioSegment.from_file(path_flac, format="flac")
flac_audio.export(path_mp3, format="mp3", bitrate='320K')
```

Load album art image from flac file and embed it into mp3 file ([follow this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346399/how-do-i-add-cover-image-to-a-mp3-file-using-mutagen-in-python)):

```
from mutagen.flac import FLAC
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, APIC

file = FLAC(path_flac)
art = file.pictures[0].data

audio = MP3(path_mp3, ID3=ID3)    
audio.tags.add(
    APIC(
        encoding=3, # 3 is for utf-8
        mime='image/png', # image/jpeg or image/png
        type=3, # 3 is for the cover image
        desc=u'Cover',
        data=art
    )
)
audio.save()
```

I successfully embed the album art into the mp3 file, and the picture showed in players such as foobar and MPC, but didn't correctly showed in file icon. If I convert the file via foobar, it correctly showed, but didn't work with mutagen.

[image: File icon (image preview) in different situation]

Does anyone knows how to make the album art correctly showed as icon?

Comment: maybe you can read your foobar version with mutagen and see how they do it?

Comment: @diggusbickus Thanks for your suggestion! I found out the solution to make album art viewable. I'll share the answer another time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for suggestion from @diggusbickus , I found and compared differences between mp3 file generated from foobar and pydub. The difference is encoding.

In pydub-converted file, which tags and album art were added by mutagen:

```
path_mp3 = 'mc_test/to/01 Lapislazuli.mp3'
file_mutagen = File(path_mp3)
file_mutagen.tags['APIC:'].encoding
```

It shows `<Encoding.UTF8: 3>`, which probably came from `audio.tags.add(APIC(encoding=3))` above.

In foobar-converted file:

```
path_mp3_foobar = 'mc_test/foobar/01 Lapislazuli.mp3'
file_foobar = File(path_mp3_foobar)
file_foobar.tags['APIC:'].encoding
```

shows `<Encoding.LATIN1: 0>`

So I change my setting to `audio.tags.add(APIC(encoding=0))` while embeding image, and it works, now I can see album art as a icon preview image. Also I do a little survey to check if other encoding number works, album art would correctly showed with encoding=0, 1 and 2.

[image]