# Edit and add ID3 tags for mp3

Tags: mp3, text-to-speech

i am creating mp3 files by gTTS (Google Text-to-Speech), a Python library and CLI tool to interface with Google Translate's text-to-speech API. How do i add images to the mp3 files. thanks

```
from mp3_tagger import MP3File, VERSION_1, VERSION_2, VERSION_BOTH
from gtts import gTTS
start = "Hello,this is  Alice ."
greetings ="That is the end of the news for today.  Have a good day. "
final_news = start + greetings
tts = gTTS(text=final_news, lang='en')
tts.save("news1.mp3") 
# Create MP3File instance.
mp3 = MP3File('news1.mp3')
# Get all tags.
tags = mp3.get_tags()
print tags
```

The output is as follows:
{'ID3TagV1': {'album': u'UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU', 'comment': u'UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU', 'artist': u'\u0443D\u0414\xac\x03HUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU', 'track': 85, 'genre': 'Bebop', 'song': u'UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU\u044f', 'year': u'UUUU'}, 'ID3TagV2': {}}

now i want to add image so that it can be diaplyed while the file is being played.

Comment: Please share your code so that we have someplace to start from.

Comment: python version: 2.7.12.  the code is displayed above.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly your **ID3 tagger library** `mp3_tagger` doesn't support image tags.
In the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/mp3-tagger/) of the library there is found the following:

> Allowed tags:
>
> ```
> - artist;
> - album;
> - song;
> - track;
> - comment;
> - year;
> - genre;
> - band (version 2.x);
> - composer (version 2.x);
> - copyright (version 2.x);
> - url (version 2.x);
> - publisher (version 2.x).
> ```

As you can see, nothing is said about the `cover` tag or something similar.

So if you want to add images like cover art to your mp3's, you will have to use another library for that.

I would recommend `eyedD3`.To add the image,  take a look at the following SO answer:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39316853/8230508)