# Convert mp3 song image from png to jpg

Tags: python, audio, mp3, eyed3

I have a set of many songs, some of which have `png` images in metadata, and I need to convert these to `jpg`.

I know how to convert `png` images to `jpg` in general, but I am currently accessing metadata using `eyed3`, which returns `ImageFrame` objects, and I don't know how to manipulate these. I can, for instance, access the image type with

```
print(img.mime_type)
```

which returns

```
image/png
```

but I don't know how to progress from here. Very naively I tried loading the image with OpenCV, but it is either not a compatible format or I didn't do it properly. And anyway I wouldn't know how to update the old image with the new one either!

**Note**: While I am currently working with `eyed3`, it is perfectly fine if I can solve this any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve this, although in a not very elegant way.

The first step is to load the image. For some reason I could not make this work with `eyed3`, but `TinyTag` does the job:

```
from PIL import Image
from tinytag import TinyTag        

tag = TinyTag.get(mp3_path, image=True)
image_data = tag.get_image()
img_bites = io.BytesIO(image_data)
photo = Image.open(im)
```

Then I manipulate it. For example we may resize it and save it as `jpg`. Because we are using `Pillow` (`PIL`) for these operations, we actually need to save the image and finally load it back to get the binary data (this detail is probably what should be improved in the process).

```
photo = photo.resize((500, 500))  # suppose we want 500 x 500 pixels
rgb_photo = photo.convert("RGB")
rgb_photo.save(temp_file_path, format="JPEG")
```

The last step is thus to load the image and set it as metadata. You have more details about this step in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39316853/5346123).:

```
audio_file = eyed3.load(mp3_path)  # this has been loaded before
audio_file.tag.images.set(
        3, open(temp_file_path, "rb").read(), "image/jpeg"
    )
audio_file.tag.save()
```